# MySql query simple question

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using a classified scripts and saves user_meta data in the wp_usermeta table.
The meta_key field is called user_address_info and in it there are all the data like below :

```
s:204:"a:7:{s:9:"user_add1";s:10:"my address";s:9:"user_add2";N;s:9:"user_city";s:7:"my city";s:10:"user_state";s:8:"my phone";s:12:"user_country";N;s:15:"user_postalcode";s:10:"comp phone";s:10:"user_phone";N;}";
```

I am not using all the fields on the script but user_add1, user_city, user_state and user_postalcode

I am having trouble to get the data using SQL like the example below (wordpress) :

```
$mylink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->links WHERE link_id = 10", ARRAY_A);
```

I would like some help here so that I will display anywhere (I dont mind using any kind of SQL queries) the requested info e.g. the user_city of current author ID (e.g. 25)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the wordpress function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Comment: thank you for your response but it can not help me. The data of the script is written in different mode as wordpress uses